How would you show review comments in a collaborative editor?
Imagine you have a system that allows you to write documents and then send them for review.
You do your best on your first review but the reviewer notices the wording could be better and leaves an inline comment on that portion of text.
You make some changes to the text and then send it back to the reviewer.
How would you expect the comment to behave:

Would you expect it to still be there but now covering the amended text?
Would you expect it to be gone?
Would you expect it to be visible somewhere else?

On one hand the comment won't longer be applicable but you may still want to see it for auditing purposes later on.


I think git platforms (GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, etc.) offer a pretty good solution in their code review interface in regard to comments:

They keep a history of all comments, together with the context in which they appeared (a few lines before and after the highlighted text).

Users can always see all comments, in all 3 states: active, reviewed, outdated.

A comment can be marked as reviewed (completed) without editing the text.

If the text is edited, the comment becomes outdated, but kept in the history of comments.

Comments can also have replies, creating threads, everything being kept in the history list.


You can check their interfaces for inspiration.

I'd recommend looking at review comments like a conversation. Provide a thread of messages with relative actions, once feedback has been addressed, let the comment hide "use a flag to mark it addressed". Let user's view past comments for some time, in case they need to look at past feedback.
